# Unable to monkey patch array using uniq in JS [beginner]

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, monkeypatching

```js
Array.prototype.uniq = function() {
  narr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
    if (!narr.include(this[i])) {
      narr.push(this[i]);
    }
  }
  return narr;
}

console.log(([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3].uniq() => [1, 2, 3]));
```

I am trying to monkey patch the above code but I receive:

> /home/cameronnc/Documents/app/skeleton/phase_1_arrays.js:11
> console.log(([1,2,2,3,3,3].uniq() => [1,2,3]));
> ^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list
> at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
>
> Node.js v18.0.0

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re actually trying to do in the console.log; why is there a malformed arrow function there at all? Are you trying to compare the results of `uniq` with another array? That is *also* suspect because that isn’t how array *contents* are checked for equality.

Comment: Awesome. I can see how this can be used in a job interview: "Lets take a look at this code snippet. What are your thoughts on this?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code. The one triggering the error is the arrow function `([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3].uniq() => [1, 2, 3])` which is not a valid arrow function. What you want is to just print the result of `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3].uniq()`.

```js
Array.prototype.uniq = function() {
  const narr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (!narr.includes(this[i])) {
      narr.push(this[i]);
    }
  }
  return narr;
}

console.log([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3].uniq());
```

Also it's not `include()` but `includes()`. Additionally your loop will run exactly `0` times since `i = 0` and your condition is `i < 0`. Change that to `i < this.length`.

By the way, by using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) you could implement the same behavior with complexity of `O(n)` instead of `O(n²)` like your current implementation.

```js
Array.prototype.uniq = function() {
  return [...new Set(this)]
}

console.log([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3].uniq());
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey, you have a few mistakes:

1. You need to declare `narr`
2. Your condition in your for loop makes no sense `i < 0`. You need the length of the array `this.length`
3. Typo `include` its `includes`

```js
Array.prototype.uniq = function() {
  let narr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (!narr.includes(this[i])) {
      narr.push(this[i]);
    }
  }
  return narr;
}

console.log([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3].uniq());
```

Comment: That’s a separate issue, though.